# SQL Server FILELISTONLY command providing incorrect logical database name

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

When using RESTORE FILELISTONLY to restore a database using code the logical_name for the files is coming back as 423.

However when I do a manual restore of the database the logical file name appears to be 3497.

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2.  Has anyone run into anything like this before?  How do I repair this?

Comment: When you say "using code" can I assume you mean you are still using [all of this jazz](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65712/backup-restore-procedure-error-sql-server-2008-r2)? And that you get different results when you use `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` *without* using code?

Comment: By "manual restore" do you mean actually restoring the database and bringing it online? How are you determining the logical file name after doing this restore? `sys.database_files`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - You caught me.  Yes sir that is what I mean.

Comment: Which question are you answering? I asked two. Can you be explicit?

Comment: @BobPusateri - by manual I'm referring to using the SSMS GUI.  Under Options the Original File Name is listed as 3497.  I've found in the past that if I hardcode my procedure to use that same value that the procedure works fine.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I'm sorry Aaron.  Yes I'm referring to the code referenced in the linked ticket when I say using code. and the without using code refers to using the SSMS GUI to do the backup and restore. Please see my comment to Bob Pusateri.

Comment: Let me ask a different way. When you do FILELISTONLY with code, you get 349. What happens when you do FILELISTONLY manually? Do you see 349 or 3497? Do you see what I'm getting at? Trying to isolate if this is a problem with your database (doubt it) or your code (highly likely).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Now I get you.  When I run the following RESTORE FILELISTONLY  FROM DISK = 'S:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\TemplateCopy\4295.BAK' I receive the 423 value.  I made a type above.  Its 423 not 349.  I'll fix that.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - So just to make sure I'm answering fully.  I get 423 both from the procedure which is referenced in the old ticket and also if I run the command listed in my previous comment.  while if I use the SSMS GUI I have a different value listed.

Comment: Where exactly did the database 4295 come from? Was it ever restored from a backup of a database named 423? I think you're tripping over yourself by using this templating system to make databases based on backups of other databases. As I suggested in your other question, you should really consider using the `model` database for this - that's exactly what it's for.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - since the front of the house can use that stored procedure to create databases from "template databases" ie just another db.  and then use those new databases to create other databases I can't tell.  I suspect that database 423 is in database 4295's ancestry at some point.  Did that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what it sounds like is happening is:

1. You create a database called `foo` with a logical data file name of `foo`.
2. You back up that database.
3. You restore that database as a different database (say, `bar`).
4. You backup the `bar` database.
5. You try to restore the `bar` backup as yet another database name, and your code assumes that the logical file name for the data file for the database `bar` should be `bar`. But it's not, it's still `foo`!

You could also interject some random `ALTER DATABASE x MODIFY FILE (name = 'y', newname = 'z');` in there to make it even more confusing for you (never mind your code). Particularly if - like it turns out is true in your case - you are storing multiple backups in a single backup file. This can be bad regardless of whether it is the same database but the logical file names change over time, or different databases being backed up to the same file. You need to determine which file number you're actually looking for, and specify that in `FILELISTONLY`'s `WITH FILE =` option. Better yet, stop reusing the same file for multiple backups.

You should be sure that when you restore a new database based on the backup of another, you use `WITH MOVE` to give the logical file names meaningful physical paths, and then use `MODIFY FILE` immediately afterward to make the logical names themselves meaningful.

To help figure out where the actual discrepancy is coming for a specific case you are experiencing (I couldn't reproduce a case where `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` showed different values than the restore UI in SSMS), you could provide a .bak file on some file sharing service, and we could look ourselves. Your description of what the file names are and what they should be is extremely hard to follow.

Comment: Yep Sorry about the file names.  They are actually all 4 digit numbers (and we have 3000 of them) for reasons that predate me.  were working on fixing that.  If I were to use Modify file on these databases now to make the logical names match the physical names is that likely to fix the issue do you think?

Comment: If they don't currently match, and your code makes assumptions about the relationship between a database's name, its files' logical names, and its files' physical names, yes.

Comment: @AaronBertand - I just wanted to take a moment and say thanks for your persistence in helping me with this problem.  I really appreciate it.  - I can use that command to set them to 423 which would allow the procedure to go forward but when I change them back it doesn't change the value coming back from filelist.  Where does filelist pull this information from? The logical file is correct in sys.master_files.

Comment: By that command I mean the ALTER DATABASE x MODIFY FILE (name = 'y', newname = 'z');  command.

Comment: @Lumpy `FILELISTONLY` pulls it from the physical backup file, it doesn't have any reason at all to check what `sys.master_files` says (after all, that backup could have come from anywhere). Also there is no guarantee that the logical name currently indicated in the system catalog is what the logical name was when the backup was taken.

Comment: Gotcha but in this case wouldn't the backup file have gotten the designation from sys.master_files?

Comment: @Lumpy in what scenario would `sys.master_files` not match the logical file name of the database? What I'm saying is that it depends on when you took the backup. What `master_files` says now is largely irrelevant (unless you took another backup).

Comment: Found it!!!  This is where having the backup file would have helped you I'm sure.  The backup file contains multiple backups.  So the FILELIST command the way that I'm using it is pulling the earliest backup logical file name.  which is not the logical file name associated with the backup I'm trying to restore.

Comment: @Lumpy this is one reason I always use `WITH INIT` and unique file names - much easier to clean up old backups, and much less chance for issues caused by changes to the same database over time, or mixing different databases in the same file. I've never understood the point of storing multiple backups in a single backup file (I know there are arguments for them, I just don't agree that they're good ones).